# Sharing a JavaScript class across multiple React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Javascript class that acts as a data controller to talk to an API.

I need to call methods of that class from multiple react components.

Currently I am storing an instance of the class in the redux store, however I understand thats a bad design approach.

How can I share a single instance across multiple components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this. Personally, I use a *provider* file to export an instance that I can import whenever I need it.

Say I need to use the same instance of a class, `Foo`, all over my app. I'd import `Foo` into a provider file that makes and exports an instance of it. Then I'd import the instance from that provider where I needed it:

File, `Foo.js`:

```
class Foo {};

export default Foo;
```

File, `FooProvider.js`

```
import Foo from './Foo';

export let foo = new Foo();
```

Component file:

```
import foo from './FooProvider';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

Class MyComponent extends Component {
    someMethod () {
        //use foo
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Sounds good to me. Or maybe export the object from class file itself. Like class Foo {};
export let foo = new Foo();